# Increase CheckedListBox Items Line Spacing

Tags: .net, vb.net, checkedlistbox

Is it possible to increase the space between items in CheckedListBox in VB.Net? How?

Comment: I absolutely loathe that control.  Drop characters like 'g' get clipped but as bad is that the "items" are just strings not virtual child controls, so you cant disable individual ones or gray them or anything.  Its a tease.  I usually use a scrolling panel with dynamically added real checkboxes so I can control the behavior, appearance and spacing.

Comment: I see. Though, I really need to use CheckedListBox.

Comment: Add a space before your "items" display value.

Comment: It'll make only the String start in space and not increase the spacing between items.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is meant by spacing.  If its Horizontal, then use the "ColumnWidth".  If you want vertical Spacing then you must inherit the control and unhide the tricky "ItemHeight" Property (see below). Its tricky in such that it changes the height on the entire control if IntergralHeight is set to TRUE.

```
Public Class CLB2
Inherits CheckedListBox

Protected _ItemHeight As Integer = 17

<Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
Public Overrides Property ItemHeight As Integer
    Get
        Return _ItemHeight
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _ItemHeight = value
        Me.ColumnWidth += 1     'Force an immediate Update
        Me.ColumnWidth -= 1
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```